# Is there a term for numbers like 0.5, 9.15, 4.22?

Tags: single-word-requests, numbers, mathematics

I know that in some country, there is a term for numbers like

```
0.5, 9.15, 4.22
```

I mean number with dot(.) in its expression.

I sought for the term in English. It was

> Decimal Number

But the term "decimal number" means just base-10 number.

```
3, 19, 277
```

Above numbers are in base-10 form, so they are decimal number (even though they do not have dot(.))

Is there a exclusive term for numbers with (.) in its expression ?

Comment: _Decimal_ can also mean 'expressing part of a whole number as a decimal rather than a fraction' - 1.5 as opposed to 1 1/2.

Comment: You seem to be looking for a classification that includes 3.14,  5.0, and 0.0 but excludes 5 and 0. In math, 5 and 5.0 represent the same number. In computer science, though, the former is represented by an integer and the latter by a float. There are some inherent difficulties with this kind of classification. So two questions: are we talking math or computer science? And does 5.0 count as a decimal number, or not count because it's also an integer?

Comment: Words often have multiple definitions. Just because _decimal_ can mean base-10 doesn’t restrict it from carrying the ‘dot’ sense such as with the phrase “to 2 decimal places”.

Comment: @rajah9 - Along with floating point there is also fixed point

Comment: @Jim and who could forget Binary Coded Decimal? *Sheepishly raises hand*

Comment: @Lawrence good point, bad example; as it could be argued that it's the "places" that carries the dot sense, not the "decimal".

Comment: @looptwalt “Place value” has the same ambiguity. :)

Comment: There was an attempt to reserve 'decimal' to cover only the subset of non-integers expressed with decimal notation, and use 'denary' to mean 'to base ten'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth an attempt by who? The noble order of guardians of the English language? (I'm not trolling, I'm genuinely curious.)

Comment: What carries the sense of "point" is "decimal point" or "point" for short. Not "decimal" on its own.

Comment: They are decimal fractions

Comment: @Lawrence '... the phrase “to 2 decimal places”' That phrase indicates expressing a quantity using a decimal numeral with two decimal places after the decimal point, to imply a precision of +-.005. Decimal means base 10 there. Expressing a similar precision would entail more binary places after the binary point if the numeral were binary. The notions of "base 10" and "point" are separate, and "decimal" refers to the former.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure ***decimal fraction*** is the technical term.

[Wikipedia: Decimal fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal#Decimal_fractions)
[Wikipedia: Decimal fractions and percentages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraction#Decimal_fractions_and_percentages)

Comment: What about 5.0? That is a number with a decimal point but has no decimal fraction.

Comment: @rajah9 5·0 has more than one meaning. It may be just a whimsical way of representing 5 (or be being used to make a point, say) or it might be a rounded figure (a result correct to 1dp).

Comment: @rajah9 to answer your question: OP hasn't yet indicated whether they want that in or out. In any case I'd argue it's a bit of an edge case.

Comment: Is there a general term for decimal fractions, binary fractions, hexadecimal fractions etc.?

Answer (score 3):

There is a term widely used in mathematics for a class of numbers that is not of the class that you seek to describe, which is a "integer", and the closely related concepts of "[whole numbers](https://www.mathsisfun.com/whole-numbers.html)" which include zero but exclude negative numbers, and of "counting numbers" which consist of whole numbers other than zero.

A **non-integer real number** would be close, but would include for example, 5 and 3/4 (which is a **mixed fraction**), as well as 5.75, so that would be somewhat broader than the word you are looking for in this case. Also, the word **non-integer** without the "real number" qualification can be taken to also include complex numbers (i.e. numbers that include the square root of -1), for example. And, **non-integer** is a word that would only be familiar to people with a fairly advanced high school level mathematics education that they have retained - it is a technical term rather than a vernacular term.

Sometimes the word **[decimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraction#Converting_between_decimals_and_fractions)** is used in isolation to mean what you say (e.g. "converting decimals to fractions"), although this word is rarely formally defined in that way in textbooks, it just gets used in this way. This is probably the best word to use to convey the meaning you intend.